# How to move application specific folder out of home folder?

Tags: 12.10, home-directory, usability, user-profile

In my `/home/myuser`I have many folder like .thunderbird, .mozilla, .skype, etc. And meaningful for human folders like Downloads, Documents, become lost among folder with configs, cache, etc. 
How to move this app-folders in specific folder?

Comment: don't do that. The config files should be hidden anyway. You should  not be able to see them. In the file manager press Ctrl-H to toggle the visibility of hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good idea, and those applications may stop working. And some applications work with `exact path to your home folder`. Usually application specific folders are hidden, so there must be no problem with `human readability`.

Answer (score 1):

**Change your point of view.**

/home/user is a *technical* directory for the specific user.
It contains the application configuration and data files for this user in some directories,
e.g. .thunderbird, ... , .config, .local, ...

These configuration and data files are generally not portable to other machines or users.
(If it is possible to reuse the configuration, your are in the "special case justifing the general case ;-)").
For example:

- host names and other resources are only valid for this installation
- absolute paths are *hard coding* the user name

Portable data like office documents, source code and multimedia data goes to different directories.

So I would move this kind of data out of the user home directory. For convenience you can add symbolic links from the physical location inside your home directory.